# Parse kml with geoxml3 in maps api v3 but stop rebuilding the sidebar when bounds/zoom changed

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml, sidebar, geoxml3

I've found a [great page](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_categories_linktoA.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/nzhistory_net_nzmap_locations_kml.xml) that demonstrates many uses of the Google Maps Api v2 and v3.

I tried to understand each line of the javascript and make something similar to what can be found on the page linked above.

However I can't understand two things:

In my application I don't want to rebuild the sidebar every time the zoom/bound/mapcenter changes. Currently the sidebar shows only placemarks that are visible on the current mapview. When the user zooms in and a placemark goes out of the view it disappears from the sidebar too. It could be annoying when you already scrolled somewhere and with only a little zooming you loose your scrolled status. Also if you bind events to sidebar elements, changing the view on the map rebuilds the sidebar and your events are finished.

I tried to rewrite the piece of code that creates categories from the placemark's `styleurl` property to apply to polylines as well not just markers, but I have no luck.

If you are deep in this kind of work please point me to the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example KML file with polylines that you want this to work with?  Removing the code that regenerates the sidebar when the map moves should have been pretty straightforward.